# Bokeh error while importing Mod "from holoext.bokeh import Mod"

Tags: python, toolbar, bokeh, holoviews

I want to be able to add functionalities like intelligent sizing, zoom-in/out, to the holoviews toolbar for neat plots. But I am not able to import Mod and get this error below:

```
    from holoext.bokeh import Mod

        ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-173777921abd> in <module>()
    ----> 1 from holoext.bokeh import Mod

ImportError: No module named bokeh
```

I installed the following packages as per requirements: https://github.com/ahuang11/holoext/blob/master/requirements.txt

```
holoext                            1.0.1
ipykernel                          4.6.1
Sphinx                             1.5.5
nbsphinx                           0.2.13
holoviews                          1.10.4
bokeh                              0.12.15
numpy                              1.14.0
pandas                             0.22.0
matplotlib                         2.1.2
dask                               0.17.0
```

I just started working with holoviews - any help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From looking at the actual package code, and the examples there, it looks like the correct import is actually:

```
from holoext.xbokeh import Mod
```

See, e.g. [this notebook example](https://github.com/ahuang11/holoext/blob/master/docs/examples/adjust_width_height_autosize.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in HoloExt>=1.0.0 I changed the module name to xbokeh instead of bokeh because of name conflicts with actual bokeh. I now see that the documentation page is not updated, still showing v0.0.3; I'll try getting that updated tonight.